# Sencha Architect 4.2 Preview Error: 404 - bootstrap.js not found

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I am doing some exercise with Sencha Architect and for each demo app, when i click 'Preview' button, nothing displays and giving this error on log:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): bootstrap.js
```

I am using trail version of Sencha Architect and using 'Commercial' licance as framework (checked on 'Project Settings') also all dependencies works fine (checked on 'Preferences').

Why is that could be or how to overcome on this error?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overcome on error:

Changed the **Project Settings**:

- General> Overwrite index file on save: unchecked (leave blank)
- Framework> Build Tools: Disabled

Then saved the project and opened *index.html* and changed script tags for ext-all.js, theme.js and link tag for theme.css to [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/extjs)' library.

Sencha CDN links not working! so imported cdnjs instead of it.